# jsTree - get only top level from checkboxes post

Tags: checkbox, jstree

I am using jsTree with the checkboxes option inside of a regular form with this configuration:

```
"checkbox" : {
    real_checkboxes : true,
    two_state: false
      }
```

I have only two levels of data (L1 and L2). If only some of the L2 items are checked, I get only those items (without the L1 item above them), which is fine. The problem is if all of the L2 items are checked, I get the top level item (L1) and all of the L2 items. I would like to get only the top level checked items, so that if all L2 items are checked I would get only the L1 item above them.

I saw there was a `.get_checked ( context, get_all )` option but I am not sure how to post the values from this to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple way would be to loop through the jQuery-result of `.get_checked` and concatenate the ids of each element to a comma separated String. You could then set the resulting String as the value of a hidden input field. You would have to split this String again on the server though.

You might also consider creating a jQuery selector for all (hidden) input elemens of checked elements and set them to unchecked. Something like

```
$("li.jstree-checked > ul input").attr('checked', false);
```

might work, though I haven't tried it out.